# What does the '^' mean in "rewrite ^ http://example.com permanent;"

Tags: 301-redirect, url-rewriting, nginx

I found some configuration of nginx contains:

```
if($args ^~ post=140) {
    rewrite ^ http://example.com/ permanent;
}
```

What does the `^` mean in `rewrite ^ http://example.com/ permanent`?

Comment: please specicy all the information that you want . i have some information of this but can't sure please chech on this link it will provide fully information od your question. http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a regexp metacharacter that matches the beginning of a string.  Since all strings have a beginning, this regexp matches any string.

This is a typical nginx idiom for "redirect any URL to `http://example.com/`".

The `$` metacharacter matching the end of a string would work as well, but `^` seems to be what everybody uses.

Comment: Just to confirm - the `^` is the first part of the `rewrite`, and what it matches, gets replaced with `http://test.com/`. So is this like doing `^.*`, and matching everything? Why does a `^` by itself, work?

Comment: @John:  Regexps are not "anchored" by default. The regexp `foo` will match any URL with the word "foo" in it.  The regexp `^foo` will match any URL starting with the word "foo".  And so the regexp `^` will match any string at all.  `.*` would work just as well, but it would probably scan the whole string and thus take longer, I suspect.